# No module named 'scrapy.conf'

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm trying to execute Twitter scraper code from: https://github.com/jonbakerfish/TweetScraper

When I run the command scrapy list in the command prompt to ensure the scraper is properly set up, I get the following error:

I have tried to install scrapy. 
Still no luck.

from scrapy.conf import settings
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scrapy.conf'".

Answer (score 1):

That code seems to have a scrapy.cfg file and is 3 years old. Might be that you have a newer version of scrapy and it's expecting a different config setup.

It changed to:

```
from scrapy import settings
```

Answer (score 0):

This is old but the solution provided doesn't work.

The error `from scrapy.conf import settings ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scrapy.conf'` is due to the versioning as it is depreciated for Scrapy > 1.6

You can access the settings in either of the 2 ways:

1. The solution provided in the documentation says -

> [The scrapy.conf module is removed, use Crawler.settings](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/extensions/feedexport.py#:%7E:text=spider.crawler.settings)

Here's a code sample using the above method. Source: [feedexport.py](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/extensions/feedexport.py#:%7E:text=spider.crawler.settings)

```
@implementer(IFeedStorage)
class BlockingFeedStorage:

    def open(self, spider):
        path = spider.crawler.settings['FEED_TEMPDIR']
```

2. You can also access the settings using -

> [from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html#run-scrapy-from-a-script)

Here's a code sample using the above method.

```
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings

settings = get_project_settings()
```